# DB connection issue with excel spreadsheet and ODBC Oracle Connect

Tags: oracle, excel, odbc

I have a spreadsheet located on a centrally hosted server.  Each day, a view on my Oracle database exports a report to this excel.  To access the document, various users across a number of locations can login and review the doc.  However, for no obvious reason, a number of locations have started being requested for the server name.  Most of the locations have the 3 fields filled in by default, but in the problem locations they have to enter the server name each time.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?  No configuration changes have been made recently, and I am fairly new to the system as a whole, and cannot come up with an explanation.
See attached screenshot for what I mean.

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKlFA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I browsed to Admin Tools > Data Sources (ODBC) and created a File DSN.  From here I was able to specify the following:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
UID=xxxxxxxxx
PWD=***************
server=xxxx.xxx.xx
```

This meant creating new database queries inside excel, I could point to this as reference and connect externally.  But more importantly for my issue, remote users could now access a server based excel, without being prompted for the server-name.  I still don't know how they lost this functionality in the first place, but this solved my issue. :)

Turns out this doesn't work - I was opening a different version of the file.  Still no sure how the connection box with excel is populated from!